# IBM Qiskit QAOA gate implementation question

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, qaoa

In section $5.2$ of the [QAOA chapter in Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/qaoa.html), section $5.2$,
state preparation uses the gate $U_{k,l}(\gamma) = e^{\frac{i \gamma}{2} (1-Z_k Z_l)}$. Later, in section $5.3$, this gate is given in terms of basic gates as $U_{k,l}(\gamma)=C_{u1}(−2 \gamma)_{k,l}u_1(\gamma)_k u_1(\gamma)_l$. Why is this the correct implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiskit gates $u_1$ and $C_{u1}$ are

$$
u_1(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix} \,\,\,
C_{u1}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

see [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U1Gate.html) and [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CU1Gate.html). Exponential of a normal matrix $A$ is the matrix $e^A$ with the same eigenbasis as $A$ and eigenvalues that are exponentials of the eigenvalues of $A$. Therefore, $u_1(\theta) = e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}(I-Z)}$. Also, note that

$$
I - Z_1 - Z_2 + Z_1Z_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix},
$$

so $C_{u1}(\theta) = e^{\frac{i\theta}{4}(I - Z_1 - Z_2 + Z_1Z_2)}$. Finally, diagonal matrices commute, so

$$
U_{k,l}(\gamma) = e^{\frac{i \gamma}{2}(I-Z_k Z_l)}
= e^{-\frac{i\gamma}{2}(I-Z_k-Z_l+Z_k Z_l)}e^{\frac{i\gamma}{2}(I-Z_k)}e^{\frac{i\gamma}{2}(I-Z_l)} = C_{u1}(-2\gamma)_{k,l} u_1(\gamma)_k u_1(\gamma)_l.
$$

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for a very clear explanation.